# Is declaring a method static when possible good practice?

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

That's pretty self-explanatory. In Java, (and all OO languages I suppose) should I declare instance method when it's the only choice or generally we don't care about it?

Comment: Depends on the requirement. But it certainly does matter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods are static when you dont need them to know about class state to process something. Helper methods are good examples of this scenario.

```
DateUtils.getDateNowInGMT()
```

The method above does not need any state to give you an answer. The one below does.

```
Withdrawer w = new Withdrawer.Builder().account(12545).build();
w.withdraw(100);
```

You cannot withdraw() money without knowing the account number, which is state associated with the Withdrawer. You could argue of course that this could be a static method and passing account information to the method would solve the problem, but it would make it inconvenient since all other methods need the same account information.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it will be more difficult for you to unit test your code if you use a lot of static methods (people consider it easier to mock an object using something like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) than mock a static method using something like [Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/)).

However, if you do not care about that, and the method uses no instance data of the class it's in, you may as well make it static.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

That's the correct approach and at least I follow that.

For example, the utility methods should be made static.

But, mostly there are many future requirments and changes required, and we can't forsee all of them today. so instance should be preferred over `static`. until unless you are following some design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

as such you can go with any kind of implementation. But rather than possibility, the criteria should be the requirement. 
if you have some operations to be performed class-wide u should opt for static methods. say for example, if you have to generate some uniqueID per instance, or you have to initialize any thing that the instances would use like display or db-driver. 
in other cases, instance methods are preferred where operations are instance specific.

Answer (score 0):

Methods should be made static only when it makes sense for them to be static. Static methods belong to the class and not to the specific instances of it. Static methods can only use other static features of the class. A static method could not call an instance method or access instance variables for example. If this makes sense for the method you are designing, then it is a good idea to use static.

Also static elements, be it variables or methods, are loaded into memory at class loading time and stay there until the end of execution or when the class-loader unloads/reloads the class it belongs to.

I use Static methods when they are meant to do computations that do not fit in the general object oriented modeling of my application. Usually utility methods such as methods to validate input data or to hold information specific to the entire application execution, or to access points to external databases are good candidates for this.

Answer (score 0):

As best of my knowledge,
If you have such a code or logic that utilize or yield something that is related to particular object state, or in simple words if your logic in side method treats different objects with some different sets of inputs and produces some different set of output, you need to take this method as instance method.
On the other side if your method has such a logic that is common for each object and the input and output doesn't depends upon object's state you should declare it as static but not instance.

```
Explaination with examples:

    Suppose you are organizing a college party and you have to provide a common coupon to the students of all departments,you just need to appoint a person for distributing a common coupon to students(without knowing about his/her department and roll no.) as he/she(person) approaches to the coupon counter. 
    Now think if you want to give the coupons with different serial numbers according to the departments and roll number of students, the person appointed by you need to get the department name and roll number of student(as input from each and every student)
    and according to his/her department and roll number he will create a separate coupon with unique serial number.

First case is an example where we need static method, if we take it as instance method unnecessary it will increase the burden.

Second case is an example of instance method, where you need to treat each student(in sense of object) separately.
```

This example may looks silly, but I hope it will help you to understand the difference clearly.